# What happens when localising with a non-prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

Given a multiplicative subset $U \subset R$ and let $L_U$ be the localization homomorphism. I am trying to figure out why $ J \subset L_U^{-1}(U^{-1}J)$.

As I understand it, when J is prime it would be equal, since $L_U^{-1}(U^{-1}J) = \{r \in R : ur \in J \text{ for some u } \in U\}$ and since $ur$ is in $J$ then $r$ must be in J since we know $u$ isn't and J is prime, but when $J$ isn't prime, I'm  struggling to visualise why it produces a subset.

Answer (score 2):

**The result**
Given a ring $R$,  a multiplicative subset $U\subset R$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset R$ we have the equivalence $$L_U^{-1}(\mathfrak p\cdot U^{-1}R) =\mathfrak p \iff  \mathfrak p\cdot U^{-1}R  \; \operatorname   {is prime in}\: U^{-1}R\iff U\cap \mathfrak p=\emptyset       \quad \quad  (\bigstar) $$ If contrariwise $U\cap \mathfrak p\neq \emptyset$, then $\mathfrak p\cdot U^{-1}R=R$, so that $L_U^{-1}(\mathfrak p\cdot U^{-1}R)=R$
**An example**
If $R=\mathbb Z$ and $U=p^\mathbb N=\{1,p, p^2,\cdots\}$ for some prime integer $p$, then the only prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subset \mathbb Z$ for which $(\bigstar)$ holds are $(0)$ and $p\mathbb Z$.
**The good news**
If on the other hand we start with a prime ideal $\mathfrak q\subset U^{-1}R$,  then we *always* have $$\mathfrak q=L_U^{-1}(\mathfrak q) \cdot U^{-1}R  \quad \quad  (\bigstar \bigstar)$$   **Anthropomorphic mnemonic**
"A prime in $R$ wanting to survive in $U^{-1}R \:$ shouldn't touch $U$"

Answer (score 0):

By definition, any $x\in J$ is sent under $L_{U}$ to $\frac{x}{1}\in U^{-1}J$. So we have indeed $J\subseteq L_{U}^{-1}(U^{-1}J)$ for any subset $J\subseteq R$.

But it is not true that this is an equality for $J$ a prime ideal. If your set $U$ contains nilpotent elements, for example, the map $L_{U}$ is just the zero map (because $U^{-1}R$ is the zero ring), so the preimage of the image of any nonempty set is the whole $R$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm finding this hard to understand. Do you have a simple example please?

Comment: Sure: the set {0,1} is multiplicative. Localizing here gives you a unique equivalence class on the localized ring, which is therefore the zero ring. The map from the ring to the localization sends everything to zero. The localized prime is also zero, but its preimage under the localization map is the whole original ring